# Find All Matches and copy side column's value <>""

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I have two sheets ("Clients", "Orders"). I want to match both by phone numbers.

In the Orders sheet I have the following table:
[image]

In the Clients sheet I have a list of Phones.

I am trying to loop to all the numbers in my Clients column, find a match in the Orders sheet that contains a mail in the side column value.

I am struggling with exiting the loop, since I don't change my variable "c", and it does not even find the mail, when it is not in the first row.

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws_clients As Worksheet
Dim ws_orders As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Phone_LookUp As Variant

Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim firstAddress As String
Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long
Dim shtCS As Worksheet, shtFD As Worksheet, rw As Range
Dim c As Range

Set shtCS = wb.Sheets("Clients")
Set shtFD = wb.Sheets("Orders")

finalrow = shtCS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With shtFD.Columns(3)
    For i = 2 To finalRow
        Set c = .Find(shtCS.Cells(i, 13).Value)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                If c.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
                    shtCS.Cells(i, 22).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    i = i + 1
                End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Should be `Dim c as range` and `Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress`. So your Find doesn't find anything? Have you stepped through your code?

Comment: Get rid of `i = i + 1` within loop. You shouldn't alter loop variable within the loop as it is incremented by the loop automatically.

Comment: If I may make a prediction based on bitter experience: You will expand more time, effort and code on making the combination of phone number and email address render a unique customer ID unnecessary than you would need to create a unique customer ID that you can rely on in every circumstance. The hurdle is that one balks at the thought of adding a dedicated sheet to the workbook to contain the list. That reluctance has no base in fact or reason. Hide the sheet and forget it, if it bothers you.

Comment: You are reversing what you are looking for and changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was identified with the intention to change the email of the customer sheet according to the order details. Using a dictionary can reduce looping.

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws_clients As Worksheet
    Dim ws_orders As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Phone_LookUp As Variant
    
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR As Variant
    Dim vPhone As Variant
    Dim Dic As Object 'Dictionary
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim s As String
    
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim shtCS As Worksheet, shtFD As Worksheet, rw As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set shtCS = wb.Sheets("Clients")
    Set shtFD = wb.Sheets("Orders")

    finalrow = shtCS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With shtCS
         vDB = .Range("M1", "M" & finalrow) 'Phone number
         Set rngDB = .Range("v1", "v" & finalrow) 'email
         vR = rngDB
    End With
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        Dic.Add vDB(i, 1), i
    Next i
    With shtFD
        vPhone = .Range("c1", "d" & .Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) 'phone, email
    End With
    r = UBound(vPhone, 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        If vPhone(i, 2) <> "" Then
            s = vPhone(i, 1)
            If Dic.Exists(s) Then
                vR(Dic(s), 1) = vPhone(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    rngDB = vR

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Lookup Using Find

**Microsoft**

- [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Both examples on this page are at least unclear if not inaccurate or worse.

> Above them, it states *"The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder,
> and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method."* and then both
> examples do not contain the `LookAt` parameter `xlPart` (substrings).
> They also differ from your case in that they are changing (replacing)
> the value in the loop, so sooner or later there will be nothing left
> to find.

- [`Range.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

Also, all three examples on this page are at least unclear if not inaccurate or worse.

> - The first is the same as one of the two on the 'Find page'.
> - In the second example, it is assumed that the `LookAt` parameter is `xlPart` (substrings). If it is also assumed that the `LookIn`
>   parameter is `xlValues` which is necessary for the `Find` method to
>   fail to find the value in a hidden row or column, the second part of
>   the 'Loop While line' will always be true, making it redundant. On the
>   other hand, if the `LookIn` parameter would be `xlFormulas` then the
>   first part would always be true, making it redundant.
> - In the third example, again it is assumed that the `LookAt` parameter is `xlPart` (substrings). It shows the benefit of the
>   `LookIn` parameter `xlFormulas` being able to find in a hidden row or
>   in this case, in a hidden column. The first part of the 'Loop While
>   line' will always be true, making it redundant.

**Your Case**

- The following is how I would handle your case (using the `Find` method). Since I want to start the 'Find' from the first cell, I'm using the last cell of the range in the `After` argument (tricky). I'm using `xlFormulas` to be able to find even if rows or columns are hidden. Then I'm using `xlWhole` to find the whole string (not the substring). I omitted the parameters of the 'also important' arguments `SearchOrder` (not necessary when one row or one column), `SearchDirection` (`xlNext` by default), and `MatchCase` (`False` by default: `A=a`).
- `Exit Do` is used to exit the `Do Loop` when an email address has been found.
- `Source` (s) and `Destination` (d) is a concept I prefer to use in cases such as yours. `Source` is read from while `Destination` is written to. In 'Lookup' cases (like yours), the `Destination` is also read from. Feel free to change (rename) these e.g. to a 'Client and Order concept' if you feel it might be more readable for you.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub lookupClientEmails()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Orders"
    Const sFirstRow As Long = 2
    Const sLookup As String = "C" ' 3
    Const sResultOffset As Long = 1 ' referring to column 'D'
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Clients"
    Const dFirstRow As Long = 2
    Const dLookup As String = "M" ' 13
    Const dResult As String = "V" ' 22
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sLastRow As Long
    sLastRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sLookup).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Cells(sFirstRow, sLookup).Resize(sLastRow - sFirstRow + 1)
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dLastRow As Long
    dLastRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dLookup).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Variables
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    ' Loop
    For i = dFirstRow To dLastRow
        Set sCell = srg.Find(dws.Cells(i, dLookup).Value, _
            srg.Cells(srg.Rows.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = sCell.Address
            Do
                If sCell.Offset(, sResultOffset).Value <> "" Then
                    dws.Cells(i, dResult).Value _
                        = sCell.Offset(, sResultOffset).Value
                    Exit Do
                End If
                Set sCell = srg.FindNext(sCell)
            Loop While sCell.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```